# Is there an SSL library in c that does not have memory leaks and uninitialized memory reads?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, valgrind

I have been integrating openssl into an application. Here is an attempt at a complete async openssl example in c. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313838/please-criticize-this-complete-async-openssl-example-in-c

However it seems that when using openssl in a real world application rather than in that example valgrind reports an incredibly large number of memory leaks and 'condition depends on uninitialized memory' errors. Some of these errors bleed over into the input used by the application so the stacks of these errors are not within the openssl library and so can not be suppressed.

It seems that openssl is not valgrind clean by design. Are there any alternatives to openssl that are valgrind clean?

Comment: Come off it. OpenSSL is embedded in Apache HTTPD, OpenLDAP, MySQL, ... These are *major* products and not one of them exhibits memory leaks. I've had all three of them running for years.

Comment: @EJP Yes, but have you run those applications under valgrind? You will see that those applications shut down with unfreed memory malloced by openssl and that they have countless uninitialized memory reads. Google for openssl and valgrind and you see for yourself that this is a well known issue.

Comment: @EJP Even the official openssl documentation acknowledges that openssl has some memory leaks which can not be cleaned up. You can read about it here https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization

Comment: @JohnCashew: what you refer to is a single leak per process (and not per context or SSL object or similar) and only on cleanup of the library, which most applications never will do anyway. Thus this is in almost all cases a non-issue. And it was actually fixed some time ago, see the referenced bug.

Comment: I agree why we shouldn't have alternate for OpenSSL that don't pay attention to resolve memory leaks? I have already dropped CURL for the same reason and did everything from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an SSL library in c that does not have memory leaks....

While OpenSSL is definitely not flawless I doubt that it has the problems with memory leaks you describe. It is used in lots of projects like nginx which write and read lots of SSL data and do a lots of SSL handshakes, so that memory leaks would surface quickly. It might be that valgrind is simply confused because [OpenSSL does it's own memory management](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7575115).

Comment: Yes I know that openssl is not valgrind clean. However the very large number of leaks and memory errors that valgrind discovers in openssl make it nearly impossible for me to use valgrind on my own application which is otherwise valgrind clean.

Comment: @JohnCashew: you might try the OpenSSL fork LibreSSL. iMHO this fork  should use the system malloc.

Comment: openssl is much cleaner under valgrind when configured with -DPURIFY and when the list of library cleanup functions is called.